# Assertion failure when writing to a text file using ofstream

Tags: c++, iostream, ofstream

I am trying to write some string data to a .txt file that i read from the user but after doing so, the program shuts down instead of continuing and when i check the results inside the .txt file i see some part of the data and then some gibberish, followed by an **assertion failure error**! Here's the code:

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
using std::ofstream;

void beginProcess();
string promptForInput();
void writeDataToFile(vector<string>);

string fileName = "links.txt";
ofstream ofs(fileName.c_str(),std::ofstream::out);

int main() {
 //  ofs.open(fileName.c_str(),std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::app);
  beginProcess();
  return 0;
}

void beginProcess() {
  vector<string> links;
  string result = promptForInput();
  while(result == "Y") {
    for(int i=0;i <= 5;i++) {
      string link = "";
      cout << "Paste the link skill #" << i+1 << " below: " << '\n';
      cin >> link;
      links.push_back(link);
    }
    writeDataToFile(links);
    links.clear(); // erases all of the vector's elements, leaving it with a size of 0
    result = promptForInput();
  }
  std::cout << "Thanks for using the program!" << '\n';
}

string promptForInput() {
  string input = "";
  std::cout << "Would you like to start/continue the process(Y/N)?" << '\n';
  std::cin >> input;
  return input;
}

void writeDataToFile(vector<string> links) {
  if(!ofs) {
    error("Error writing to file!");
  } else {
    ofs << "new ArrayList<>(Arrays.AsList(" << links[0] << ',' << links[1] << ',' << links[2] << ',' << links[3] << ',' << links[4] << ',' << links[5] << ',' << links[6] << ',' << "));\n";
 }
}
```

*The problem lies probably somewhere in the ofstream writing procedure but i can't figure it out.* Any ideas?

Comment: the gibberish may give useful hints as to what is happening. is there a call stack to go with the assert fail? sample input to provoke the error? semantically, what you do seems to be open code injection vulnerability (are the contents of the target file executed?). pay attention to the actual count of elements, you are writing 0..6 = 7 elements but asking for 0..5 = 6 elements.

Comment: the sample input is : 1,2,3,4,5,6. You're right i am trying to access the 7th element of a 6 element vector(i'll fix that asap). I tried pasting the output file here but it's 66k chars long ! Should i paste like the first few lines of it?

Comment: you got an answer addressing the index/count issue already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be filling a vector of 6 elemenents, with indices 0-5, however in your writeDataToFile function are dereferencing links[6] which is out of bounds of your original vector.

Another thing which is unrelated to your problem, but is good practice:

```
void writeDataToFile(vector<string> links)
```

is declaring a function which performs a copy of your vector. Unless you want to specifically copy your input vector, you most probably want to pass a const reference, like tso:

```
void writeDataToFile(const vector<string>& links)
```

Comment: Thank you very much @divinas the error was caused due to me trying to access the 7th element of a 6 element vector. I corrected that and also implemented the best practice mentioned above. Thanks for the useful info! Have a good one